# I have a ParserError here "function Stratus(string _greeting) {"

Tags: solidity, error

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Stratus {

    string public greeting;
    address public owner;

    event GreetingChanged (string oldGreeting, string newGreeting)

    function Stratus(string _greeting) {
        greeting = _greeting;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function setGreeting (string _greeting){
        require(owner == msg.sender)
        GreetingChanged(greeting,_greeting)
        greeting = _greeting
        }
    }
```

Comment: please edit your question and show us what error says

Comment: use 0.5.0 or at least 0.4.24 man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of solidity you are using is very old. The latest stable compiler for solidity is `version:0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang`. You can use the following code to remove the above error. But you have to use the latest version of solidity.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;

contract Stratus {

    string public greeting;
    address public owner;

    event GreetingChanged (string oldGreeting, string newGreeting);

    constructor(string memory _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function setGreeting (string memory _greeting) public {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        emit GreetingChanged(greeting,_greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
        }
    }
```

If you want to get ABI and Bytecode of above contract then you can get it by pasting the code in [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&evmVersion=null&appVersion=0.7.7&version=soljson-v0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.js).

[image]

But first, Change the compiler version in the remix to `version:0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang`

[image]

Use the older layout of remix if its showing new layout.

[image]

**Changes I made:**

1. I added newer version of solidity as `pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;`
2. I added semi-colon after some instructions
3. I added keyword `public` for the function, you can also make them private
4. I added keyword `memory` as if we are creating an array as a parameter of a function then we have to reserve memory for it first.
5. We have to use `emit` in latest solidity if we are calling a function which is not returning a value.

You can also check the syntax of latest stable version of the [solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.8/).